# How can I rewrite this React Component as a pure function and get an error/warning free implementation with React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've been struggling with rewriting this react component to a pure function per my eslint error recommendations. My goal is to also get this to work with react router without it throwing a warning/error.

Here is the class component:

```
class PrivateRouteContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {
      isAuthenticated,
      component: Component,
      ...props
    } = this.props

    return (
      <Route
        {...props}
        render={props =>
          isAuthenticated
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : (
            <Redirect to={{
              pathname: '/login',
              state: { from: props.location }
            }} />
          )
        }
      />
    )
  }
}
```

source: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-redux/examples/AuthExample.js

Here is my eslint error: 
[image: Pure Function eslint error]

Here is my attempt:

```
const PrivateRouteContainer = (props) => {
  const {
    isAuthenticated,
    isLoggingIn,
  } = props;

  return (
    <Route
      {...props}
      render={() =>
        (isAuthenticated || isLoggingIn
          ? <Component {...props} />
          : (
            <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/login',
            state: { from: props.location },
          }}
            />
        ))
      }
    />
  );
};
```

This doesn't seem to work as I'm getting the error:
**Warning: You should not use and in the same route; will be ignored**

Here are my route definitions if it helps:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';

import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute';

import Login from '../containers/LoginPage';
import Home from '../containers/HomePage';
import List from '../containers/ListPage';
import Edit from '../containers/EditPage';

import { logout } from '../redux/auth/oauth/actions';

const ConnectedSwitch = connect(state => ({ location: state.routerReducer.location }))(Switch);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isLoggingIn: state.authReducer.isLoggingIn,
  isAuthenticated: state.authReducer.isAuthenticated,
  error: state.authReducer.error,
});

const Logout = connect(mapStateToProps)(({ dispatch }) => {
  dispatch(logout());
  return <Redirect to="/" />;
});

const Routes = props =>
  (
    <ConnectedRouter history={props.history}>
      <ConnectedSwitch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={connect(mapStateToProps)(Home)} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/list" exact component={List} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/edit" component={Edit} />
        <Route path="/login" exact component={connect(mapStateToProps)(Login)} />
        <Route path="/logout" exact component={Logout} />
      </ConnectedSwitch>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  );
Routes.propTypes = {
  history: PropTypes.shape({}).isRequired,
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Routes);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a typo as I think you understood "this" is not defined in a stateless component :

```
const {
    isAuthenticated,
    isLoggingIn,
} = props; // <-- remove this. here
```

Comment: yes, I noticed that soon after posting. Updating my original post above. thx

Answer (score 0):

```
const PrivateRouteContainer = (props) => (
  <Route
    {...props}
    render={() =>
      (props.isAuthenticated || props.isLoggingIn
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : (
          <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/login',
            state: { from: props.location },
          }}
          />
        ))
    }
  />
)
```

Comment: This still returns: 
Warning: You should not use <Route component> and <Route render> in the same route; <Route render> will be ignored

Comment: This has nothing to do with Pure Components. It's a library warning from react-router.

Comment: You're right - I was having difficulty formulating the question here as it seems like I had two goals. 1 - rewrite the component class and also get a warning/error free implementation with react-router. I'll update my question. Thx for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing authentication as props, have you considered creating a utils file, such as `auth.js` that easily returns if the user is validated or not?

If we tangle the authentication conditions within component disposition we're adding an additional layer which we're going to have to care about, which is having to care about the parent component's life cycle and how it evaluates to authentication. This also means you're passing to the `<Route />` component, some props that it doesn't care or doesn't need to care about, and that could be problematic as well

To  make things clearer, also try using the object destructuring property instead of declaring const inside of your component, as well as the rest operator. Pass to route only what route needs, and to `<Component />`, only what component needs. That could be causing errors,

The final result is something like this:

```
import { isAuthenticated } from 'utils/auth';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    isAuthenticated() ? (
      <Component {...props} />
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login' }} />
    )
 )}/>
);
```

Comment: I like this idea but I'm using redux to pass in props from global state to PrivateRoute (isAuthenticated, isLoggingIn) so I'm not sure how I'd run mapStateToProps on just the Route in this case. Also, would this address the error : Warning: You should not use <Route component> and <Route render> in the same route; <Route render> will be ignored???

Comment: When I try to implement this, I get the following errror: 
Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best approach or not, but it seems to be working...

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const RedirectToLogin = () => (
  <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login' }} />
);

const PrivateRouteContainer = props => (
  <Route
    {...props}
    component={props.isAuthenticated || props.isLoggingIn ?
      props.component :
      RedirectToLogin}
  />
);

PrivateRouteContainer.propTypes = {
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  isLoggingIn: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  component: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const PrivateRoute = connect(state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.authReducer.isAuthenticated,
  isLoggingIn: state.authReducer.isLoggingIn,
}))(PrivateRouteContainer);

export default PrivateRoute;
```